# CATIA Annotation to Usersurface link

Tags: vba, catia

I have been trying to get surface data from annotation and measure the curve and check if the annotation mentioned correctly or not.

using
`annotation.getsurfaces(variant1())`
but this is returning a string instead of surface.
I cant goto surface by using
`part1.createreferencefromname(variant(0))` or `part1.findobjectbyname(variant(0))`
I need to measure that surface returned from `annotation.getsurfaces(variant1())`

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have played with annotations a very little so I might not give the best answer.
You could change the string from something like this (sorry i make myself a extrude :))

```
"Part1/Geometrical Set.1/Extrude.1/Face"
```

To

```
"Part1/Geometrical Set.1/!Extrude.1"
```

Then use

```
Dim PartDoc as PartDocument 'your part document
Dim Ref as Reference

Set Ref = PartDoc.Product.CreateReferenceFromName("Part1/GeometricalSet.1/!Extrude.1")
```

Another option is get the name of the feature `"Extrude.1"` and use:

```
Dim Shape as HybridShape 'here you have to declare the right type for you
Set Shape = PartDoc.Part.FindObjectByName("Extrude.1")
```

Be careful because you can get differed object if you have the same with same name somewhere else!

You can explore the BRep sytax more if you are brave enough and create something like this (just example from api documentation)

```
CreateReferenceFromName("Produit1/Column_2/!Selection_FVertex:(Vertex:(Neighbours:(Face:(Brp:(StrFunRibSweep.1;0:(Brp:(GSMLine.1);Brp:(IntSection.1;9999)));None:();Cf11:());Face:(Brp:(StrFunRibSweep.1;1);None:();Cf11:());Face:(Brp:(StrFunRibSweep.1;0:(Brp:(GSMLine.1);Brp:(IntSection.1;10018)));None:();Cf11:()));Cf11:());StrFunRibSweep.1;Z0;G4702)")
```

To measure something you can use the object `Measurable` from `Space Analysis` and there you can use `Func GetMeasurable(Reference iMeasuredItem) As Measurable`

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
but most of the time the annotation is linked to an edge on the surface or thickness attribute like a hole or a slot. I need to measure the radius of the edge or length of the slot. Is there any solution for that case